# Ideas on how to create instagram like image feed website, capable of roller overs as well

Tags: jquery, html, css, php-7, rollover

I am wanting to make a website which allows clients to upload images (to be part of a roll over) onto a server, which will then get displayed on the main page of the site in a Instagram-like fashion.

I have already created PHP scripts for securely uploading images; storing details in a Mysql database; displaying then on a webpage;

By Instagram-like fashion i mean the like their website, where you scroll down and up through posts and the webpage and the webpage loads further images once you reach the bottom.

**So the main question is: How to create main page where the database image feed continuously loads more posts when you scroll down to the bottom.**

I know I am making life hard for myself by doing this as it is way easier just to use PHP templates and make the user click onto the next set of images (rollovers), but i do like a challenge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grab the scroll position of the bottom of the page using JavaScript, and then make an Ajax call to load the next x number of posts when the user scrolls to a given point.

Answer (score 0):

After Kai's answer i found this quite useful blog-post:
[Reusable ajax script/tutorial to load more posts with get_posts](http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/7846)